Node.js and Express application running on Azure App Service Linux using PM2 only works on port 8080
I am trying to use PM2 on Azure App Service Linux running a simple Node.js/Express application. The configuration file for PM2 is like this:
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "myapi",
      script: "./src/index.js",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
        PORT: 3000,
      },
      env_test: {
        NODE_ENV: "test",
        PORT: 8081,
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        PORT: 8080,
      }
    }
  ]
};

The startup command is like
pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env test

The deployment is fine. But I can only use PORT = 8080. If I use port 8081, I got the 504 gateway timeout error.
What might be the problem?

The most likely issue is that WEBSITE_PORT has been set to 8080. You need to update that or use EXPOSE on the container to open other ports.

I checked my Azure website environment varibles, I didn't see WEBSITE_PORT or PORT settings. I saw in the log stream that docker seems to start like "docker run -d -p 4858:8080 --name my-api-test_0_100db2d2 ...", even if I set the port in ecosystem.config.js to 8081. Maybe there is docker configuration file somewhere that I don't know. But I didn't use Docker directly.

@user3616544 Try to set Port value process.env.PORT || 8080 in your configuration file.

@user3616544 If possible, share your GitHub repo?

Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

By default, Azure Web Apps only allow external access on ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). On Azure Linux Web Apps, containers typically run on port 8080.
It is not possible to expose multiple ports for external access in an Azure Web App.
I created a sample Node.js Express app with PM2 and deployed it to Azure App Service (Linux).
The app should be configured to listen on the port specified by process.env.PORT for compatibility with Azure’s port routing.
Below is complete code of nodejs app.
ecosystem.config.js:
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: "myapi",
        script: "./src/index.js",
        env: {
          NODE_ENV: "development",
          PORT: 3000, 
        },
        env_test: {
          NODE_ENV: "test",
          PORT: process.env.PORT || 8080, 
        },
        env_production: {
          NODE_ENV: "production",
          PORT: process.env.PORT || 8080, 
        }
      }
    ]
  }; 

index.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

I used the below start script in package.json :
"scripts": {
"start": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js"
},

I set the Startup Command as shown below.


Azure Output :


Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
